# Getting value formatted as ["example"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, netldap

I'm working with NET-LDAP API using Ruby on Rails:

```
@ldap.search( :base => @treebase, :filter => @filter ) do |entry|
  entry.cn
```

When I get the `entry.cn` value it comes formatted as `["example"]`
How do I get this value without the characters `[" "]`?

Comment: it looks like an array, you can just do `entry.cn[0]` to access it.

Comment: @davidhu2000 It works. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`["example"]` means that you've got an array with one string.

To get the first element of an array in Rails you can call:

```
["example"].first
```